# Cannot receive memory usage or cpu usage in output

Tags: powershell

Trying to find the top 5 services using CPU power. I also would like to add in memory usage. When I run this script in PS, I receive the output in a csv, but only the service name and description are shown. I have tried to use Get-Counters, but I receive an error with "counter path is invalid", or "Specified counter could not be found". Help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
$services = Get-Service | Sort-Object CPU -Descending | Select-Object -First 5

$serviceInfo = @()

foreach ($service in $services) {
$serviceName = $service.Name
$cpu_usage = $service.CPU
$mem_usge = [Math]::Round(($service.WorkingSet / 1MB), 2)

   
$serviceDescription = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Service | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $serviceName}).Description
    
    
    $serviceDetails = [PSCustomObject]@{
        "Service Name" = $serviceName
        "CPU Usage (%)" = $cpu_usage
        "Memory Usage (MB)" = $mem_usage
        "Description" = $serviceDescription
    }
    
    
    $serviceInfo += $serviceDetails

    }

    $serviceInfo | Export-Csv -Path "ServiceReport.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: `Sort-Object CPU -Descending` isnt doing anything in your code, the service objects dont have a `CPU` property

Comment: I think you have a confusion between service and process ? please clarify

Answer (score 0):

There's no property for CPU usage for services. This code will do what you want for processes but I don't believe there is a similar option for services

```
get-Process | Sort-Object CPU -descending
```